# Group data values using xpath & php

Tags: php, xml, api, xpath

So my XML document looks something like this:

```
<output>
   <workouts>
       <workout>
         <workout_date>
           <![CDATA[ 2014-04-05 ]]>
         </workout_date>
         <distance>
           <![CDATA[ 15 ]]>
         </distance>
       </workout>
       <workout>
         <workout_date>
           <![CDATA[ 2014-04-08 ]]>
         </workout_date>
         <distance>
           <![CDATA[ 2 ]]>
         </distance>
       </workout>
       <workout>
         <workout_date>
           <![CDATA[ 2014-03-28 ]]>
         </workout_date>
         <distance>
           <![CDATA[ 3.3 ]]>
         </distance>
       </workout>

   </workouts>
</output>
```

Now I am using XPath and PHP to output the date like so:

```
$typesListXml = $xml->xpath('output/workouts/workout/workout_date');
if (!empty($typesListXml)) {
    $typesList = array();
    foreach ($typesListXml as $typeXml) {
             // using strtotime to output the month only (commented out below)
        //$typesList[] = date('F', strtotime((string)$typeXml));
                $typesList[] = (string)$typeXml;
   
    }
    
    //var_dump($typesList);
    $typesList = array_unique($typesList);
    var_dump($typesList);
```

This will output only unique values so I'm not repeating each month, however, I'm not able to output the sum of all the `"distance"` values for each month.  So essentially, the final result will look something like this:

Result:

> April
>
> total distance =  17
>
> March
>
> total distance = 3.3
>
> etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to group them using this logic.  Just need to add the distance values from the array now

```
 $distanceforDate = array();
    foreach ($typesList as $type) {
     $Data = $xml->xpath('output/workouts/workout[workout_date="' . $type . '"]');
        $M = date('F', strtotime($type));
        if (!empty($Data)) {
            foreach ($Data as $rawData) {
                //print_r ($M);
                $distanceforDate[$M][] = '' . $rawData->distance;
            }
        }
    }
  print_r($distanceforDate);
    echo array_sum($distanceforDate);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if PHP provides XPath/XQuery 3 support or not, but if it does you could achieve what you are looking for with this expression:

```
for $workout in /output/workouts/workout
let $date := xs:date($workout/workout_date)
let $month := month-from-date($date)
let $year := year-from-date($date)
group by $year, $month
return
    let $padded-month := substring(concat('0', $month), string-length(string($month)))
    let $month-year := format-date(xs:date(string-join((string($year), $padded-month, '01'), "-")), "[MNn] [Y]")
    return
        ($month-year, sum($workout/distance))
```